# How to code HTML with URL Rewriting as directory

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used `.htaccess` in the past to rewrite my URLs.

I used things like this:

```
RewriteRule event-([0-9]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ /event.php?id=$1 [L]
```

BUT really prefers directory style:

```
RewriteRule ^events/([a-z]+) events.php?cat=$1 [NC]
```

My question is that it has always bothered me in the HTML with the directory style to add this kind of code to link images, `includes();` and other links when the directory gets long when with the first style I don't have to change anything.

```
../../../images.jpg

../../../../../script.php
```

Is there an other way to code this because it's really bad like thisnd gets on my nerves each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the folder structure like :

```
css [folder]
images [folder]
event.php
events.php
index.php
etc.
```

You could use in your html : [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) and at that point you can just link your css and images like normal.